# Excel VBA how to add source sheet name to copied row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add the sheet name to a copied row in another sheet?
I've got this code to move a row from one sheet to another

```
Sub move_row()

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("Log")

'Select Entire Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Lets say that I have this scenario:
I have 3 sheet named: parts1,parts2,log
The code above moves the entire row from the active sheet (which uses only column A and B) to the log sheet. but some times entry in parts1 and parts2 are the same, and I want to know from which it was moved by adding the sheet name in column C of the pasted row.
Is it possible?

Comment: try `sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name` when setting your variables and then something like `sht1.Range("C1").Value = sheetName` at the end of your sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'd use `ActiveSheet.Name`.  `Selection.Parent.Name` may be better as `ActiveSheet` may change while the code is running, but there again so may `Selection`.

Also, adding the source sheet name into a cell may overwrite a value as you're copying the entire row.  Maybe add it as a comment?

```
Sub Move_Row()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
    lastrow = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection.EntireRow
        .Copy Destination:=sht1.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
        .Delete
    End With

    With sht1.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Text Text:="Source Sheet: " & Selection.Parent.Name
        Else
            .Comment.Text Text:=.Comment.Text & Chr(10) & "Source Sheet: " & Selection.Parent.Name
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

**Note:** The code doesn't actually select the `EntireRow`, it just references it.

Answer (score 0):

please try this out with the following speed improvements. A new variable is assigned to keep track of the source sheetname, and is copied to Column C of the corresponding row in the target sheet.

```
Sub move_row()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Declare variables
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("Log")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
sheetName = sht2.Name

'Select Entire Row
Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
lastRow = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Selection
    .Copy Destination:=sht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
'After pasting and deletion of row, include the source sheet name in the         same row at column 3 (i.e. Column C)
sht1.cells(lastrow+1,3) = sheetName

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```
Sub move_row()

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim strShtName as String 'name of active sheet

'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("Log")

'Select Entire Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Select

'assign name of active sheet
    strShtName = ActiveSheet.Name

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection
        .Copy Destination:=sht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With

'put sheet name in column C
    sht1.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Value = strShtName

End Sub
```